# I can't access special vehicles as any 3 characters in GTA 5 - PS4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So this is the problem. When I wait a few moments in my garage, (not the garage connected to the house) I should expect the special vehicles directions to come up but instead it says the following 'Special vehicles can be collected here. Visit playstation@store to find new downloadable content.' WTF? What does one do in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to go near the opposite wall facing entrance/corner of the garage to get the menu for special cars selection.

Comment: can you please post a reason for the down vote?